# Bluetooth abruptly shuts down in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bluetooth

I have a lenovo Y510p, and have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it. 
My built-in bluetooth in my laptop abruptly shuts down and my music switches to my laptop speakers. 
I cannot switch it on again using the GUI.
The command `sudo service bluetooth restart` does not help either.

It usually helps if I restart, but that's quite annoying.

I have this output from the command `sudo service bluetooth status` .

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: active (running) since อา. 2018-01-14 17:12:06 +07; 12s ago
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
 Main PID: 31229 (bluetoothd)
   Status: "Running"
   CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
           └─31229 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

ม.ค. 14 17:12:06 firdaus-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y510P bluetoothd[31229]: Not enough free handles
ม.ค. 14 17:12:06 firdaus-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y510P bluetoothd[31229]: Current Time Service could not be registered.
ม.ค. 14 17:12:06 firdaus-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y510P bluetoothd[31229]: gatt-time-server
ม.ค. 14 17:12:06 firdaus-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y510P bluetoothd[31229]: Not enough free handles
ม.ค. 14 17:12:06 firdaus-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y510P bluetoothd[31229]: Not enough free handles
ม.ค. 14 17:12:06 firdaus-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y510P bluetoothd[31229]: Sap driver initialization failed.
ม.ค. 14 17:12:06 firdaus-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y510P bluetoothd[31229]: sap-server: Operation not permitted (1)
ม.ค. 14 17:12:06 firdaus-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y510P bluetoothd[31229]: Endpoint register
ม.ค. 14 17:12:06 firdaus-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y510P bluetoothd[31229]: Endpoint register
ม.ค. 14 17:12:16 firdaus-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y510P bluetoothd[31229]: Failed to set m
```

Comment: Same for my Thinkpad T460p